# Straightening the level sets of a smooth function

Tags: differential-topology

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function and
$D\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a closed ball such that $f$ has no critical points
on $D$: $\nabla f(x)\neq0$ for $x\in D$.
**My question:** Can we find a homeomorphism/diffeomorphism $\varphi
:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ p_{1}\varphi(x)=f(x)$ for any $x\in D$,

where $p_{1}:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is the first coordinate
$p_{1}(x)=x_{1}$? Note that this implies that any set $f^{-1}(c)\cap D$ is
send by $\varphi$ into $p_{1}^{-1}(c)\cap\varphi(D)$, so it should be
embeddable in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$. In this sense, $\varphi$ is straightening
the level sets of $f$ near $D$. (And probably\ we may require in addition that
$\varphi$ is straightening the gradient flow of $f$ near $D$, making the flow
lines parallel to $Ox_{1}$).

I am mainly interested in cases $n=2$, $n=3$. I considered some simple
examples for $n=2$, indicating that at least in this case the conjecture is true.

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem with the critical points of $f$ restricted to the boundary of $D$. They will pass into "turn points" of the boundary of $\varphi(D)$. I don't claim that $\varphi(D)$ is convex.

Comment: I suppose your question could be re-phrased as a question about closed index-zero everywhere-nonzero $1$-forms on $TS^{n-1} \oplus \epsilon^1$, where $\epsilon^1$ is the trivial bundle over the sphere.  The question you're asking is if every such $1$-form is the pull-back along an embedding $S^{n-1} \to \mathbb R^n$ of the form $dx_1$.  Here the induced map from $\epsilon^1$ to the tangent bundle is defined geometrically, using orthogonal complements.

Comment: My question was provoked by an elementary observation: If $v$ is a smooth flow in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ without singularities, then there is an immersion $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{2}$ which is straightening $v$, i.e. the image $\varphi(\lambda)$ of any flow line $\lambda$ is parallel to $Ox$. Here $\varphi$ is not supposed to be "onto". This fails to be true in dimension $\geq3$. By the way, I don't know the right citation place for this claim, although I have encountered similar things in the literature.

Comment: Add. to prev. comment: Although $\varphi$ cannot be assumed to be globally one-to-one, for any closed disk $D\subset$ $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ we may find $\varphi$ so that $\varphi|_{D}$ is a homeomorphism.